# Pandas: how to create two new columns in a dataframe with an existing string data column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a column date (string type for each row) in my dataframe that looks like this:

```
1      'Sat, 26 Dec 2020 14:05:59 +0000'
2      'Sat, 26 Dec 2020 11:01:27 +0000'
3      'Sat, 26 Dec 2020 12:43:59 +0000'
4      'Sat, 26 Dec 2020 13:24:45 +0000'
5      'Sat, 26 Dec 2020 13:37:00 -0000'
```

I would like to create two new columns like this:

```
Date                Hour
'Sat, 26 Dec 2020'   '14:05:59'
'Sat, 26 Dec 2020'   '11:01:27'
```

How can I do this ?
Knowing that at the beginning the type is string.
I thought about cutting with the len because the format is always the same for each row at the beginning.
But maybe it's not the best method.

Answer (score 2):

assuming your original column name is `datetime` you can do the following:

```py
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['datetime']).dt.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y')
df['time']=pd.to_datetime(df['datetime']).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```